# How change root folder for nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have modules that I should use on client-side and server-side. 
My structure look like:

```
rootfolder/clientside/...
rootfolder/serverside/...
rootfolder/shared/...
```

I'm trying to get access from the server:

```
import DisputeStatus from "shared/models/dispute/disputeStatus"; - on linux os it works
```

Do you know a solution for Windows OS?

**UPDATED**

I can make relative path on server, but client side throw

> Module not found: You attempted to import  which falls outside of the
>   project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not
>   supported.

Comment: `from "../shared`, whats the error on windows?

Comment: for server no, but for clientside with react - yes

Comment: The root of the server is "rootfolder" or "rootfolder/serverside"? If it's "rootfolder" then there is no reason for this to not work. Anyway, have you tried `path.join(__dirname, '..', 'sharedfolder')`? I noticed you are using ES6, I don't know if the use of path.join is the same for ES6 and CommonJS.